# Doctrine OneToOne incorrectly? generating a UNIQUE INDEX

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

SchemaTool is generating unique index for associations that are OneToOne. I believe this is incorrect.

Section 6.6 of the Associations manual page at Doctrine shows an example of a OneToOne for a Product has one Shipping. This is shown to generate the Product table:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    shipping_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, with the same code for my entity User has one Organisation, my User table SQL is generated as

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    organisation_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQ_3B978F9FA7F43455 (organisation_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This prevents me adding 2 users with the same Organisation. Not correct.

I additinally tried to be verbose with the unique JoinColumn annotation param.

```
@JoinColumn(name="organisation_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique="false")
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to find anything at all about this.

Thanks

Comment: `1-to-1` relationships have that feature...

Comment: If you want many users in an organisation, then you want a `1-to-many` relationship.

Comment: But the 1-to-1 example at Doctrine is Product OneToOne Shipping. If this is a feature that would mean Products could not share the same Shipping method, which seems wrong. Shipping options should be able to be used by many Products.

Comment: It looks like ManyToOne from User to Organisation would generate the SQL I need. I guess I don't fully understand the OneToOne example at Doctrine.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that example? And a ShippingMethod is different than a Shipping. Probably it means something else than what you think it means.

Comment: 1 to 1 means that one instance is connected to one instance, and nobody else is connected. what you need is many-to-one/one-to-many. in the shipping example it's the shipping instance which is used by a single product

Comment: A simple example of a `1-to-1` relationship would be `User` and `Admin.`

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional - you can see no UNIQUE INDEX is created according to the SQL example.

Comment: ManyToOne it is, thanks everyone. The Doctrine docs. confused me as the SQL output it shows for OneToOne does not add a unique constraint, but in reality it does.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is an error there. One to one relationships should be a reference between two `PRIMARY` keys or a `PRIMARY` and a `UNIQUE` key or two `UNIQUE` keys.

Comment: @ypercube is right.  I first thought they meant shipping method, but it probably means a per-order shipping object that lists e.g. date shipped, date signed for, etc.

Comment: I was just about to ask this question, glad I found the answer here!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If One organisation has Many Users and Many Users have One and only one organisation then it's not a One-to-One association.

One-to-One associations have to be unique.

Your association is `ManyToOne` on the User side and `OneToMany` on the organisation side.

User.php

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organisation")
 */
private $organisation;
```

Organisation.php

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="organisation")
 */
private $users;

function __construct() {
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a YML version could help someone else starting with doctrine/symfony. Here is my version of it:

**`User.orm.yml`**

```
manyToOne:
    organisation:
        targetEntity: Organisation
        joinColumn:
            name: organisation_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**`Organisation.orm.yml`**

```
oneToMany:
    users:
        targetEntity: User
        mappedBy: organisation
        joinColumn:
            name: organisation_id
            referencedColumn: id
```

Hope it helps.