# Attribute unique in one to one relationship - Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-one

I have decided to implement a recursive one-to-one relationship for the category entity:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */

class Category{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="father_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $father;

.................
some methods
.................
}
```

A category that does not have a parent will have its attribute "parent" in null. A daughter category of another category, will have the id of its parent category. The problem arises when there are two categories that have the same father. The error is as follows:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO category (name, father_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["new category", 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_4E10122D613CEC58'
```

The problem is that for some reason, the "father" attribute by default is "unique = true". I have tried to change this attribute, setting "unique = false" but it does not work.

I listen to possible solutions to this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are using `OneToOne` instead of `ManyToOne`, thus Doctrine adds a unique constraint on your `father_id` foreign key. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8205606/9135269) discusses this behaviour in more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine OneToOne incorrectly? generating a UNIQUE INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205606/doctrine-onetoone-incorrectly-generating-a-unique-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a one to one relaltion, the "father" category can only have one "daughter"category. What you want is that a category "Father" can have several categories "daughter". You need a [one-to-many relationship self-referencing.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)